# Provisioning profile install problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I used the Development Provisioning Assistant to get: 
- mobile provisioning profile 
- developer_identifier.cer

I did as it said but "step 3: Verify the Private and Public keys in the Keychain" is not showing any keys (public and private keys).

How do I get the keys ?  thx

(also note that I am loading this onto my laptop where this has already been done on a MacMini)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you download the keys from the iOS dev center, you double-click on the `.cer` files, and they should get loaded into your keychain.

Comment: I see the cert  but not any keys.

Comment: @Kristen What if you double-click on the certificate in Keychain Access?

Comment: I am wondering if only one machine can be worked on.  I was never asked to submit a cert by the Provisioning Assistant, which should had happened near the beginning.

Comment: If you try on more than one I think you have to deactivate the older one (you export your developer profile and then import it).  Maybe that 'Export' from Xcode is what you're missing?